# JS Array.splice return original Array and chain to it

Tags: javascript, splice

I have a string with values like this `a,b,c,d` and want to remove a specific letter by index

So here is what I did `str.split(',').splice(1,1).toString()` and this is (obviously) not working since `splice` is returning the values removed not the original array

Is there any way to do the above in a one liner?

```js
var str = "a,b,c,d";
console.log(str.split(',').splice(1,1).toString());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: You could use arr.slice()https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `filter` and add `condition` as `index != 1`.

```js
var str = "a,b,c,d";
console.log(str.split(',').filter((x, i) => i != 1).toString());
```

Comment: Would you know in terms of performance, would this be faster then just doing it in 2 lines?

Comment: Filter is `O(n)` while splice is `O(1)`. But performance differences in this simple case are really negligible.

Comment: Please review https://medium.com/@justintulk/javascript-performance-array-slice-vs-array-filter-4573d726aacb to know about performance. `splice` is definitely `faster`.

Answer (score 4):

Another strange solution. Destructure the array, remove the unwanted index, get an object and join the values of it.

```js
var string = "a,b,c,d",
    { 1: _, ...temp } = string.split(',')

console.log(Object.values(temp).join(','));
```

Answer (score 3):

The **alternate way** using regex replace

```js
var str = "a,b,c,d";

console.log(str.replace(/,\w+/, ''))
```

Comment: I tried to think of one, but I always add /g in my head :)

Comment: @mplungjan /g becomes a habit :)

Answer (score 2):

Splice works in place, so oneliner is

```js
const arr = "a,b,c,d".split(','); arr.splice(1,1); console.log(arr.toString());
```

If you want an string in a oneliner, you have to hardcode the index in a filter

```js
console.log("a,b,c,d".split(',').filter((item, i) => i != 1).toString())
```

Or two slices (not performant at all)

```js
const arr = "a,b,c,d".split(',')
console.log([...arr.slice(0,1),...arr.slice(2)].toString())
```

Comment: I guess you need to use semicolons instead of linebreaks - OP is asking for a one-liner :-)